# Using a PHP session and Javascript to set a cookie - possibly redundant?

Tags: javascript, cookies, php

I am using PHP sessions to protect access to my CMS without being logged in. It's working, but I'm also setting a cookie using JavaScript so that users are redirected to the CMS from the login.php page if they have already authenticated. The cookie's expiration is 1 day, but I'm starting to wonder whether using a session and having a cookie is a bit redundant?

Can I use PHP sessions alone to accomplish these two tasks?

EDIT: To clarify - I set a PHP session variable on the login.php page. If you try to access the cms.php page, it will check to see if that session variable exists. If not, it knows you didn't come from the login page and it will redirect you.

I was under the impression that PHP sessions were destroyed when the browsing session ends, and I was using JavaScript to do some other work, so I Googled 'how to set a cookie using javascript' and did it that way (having never set a cookie before). I don't want the user to have to login each time just because they closed their browser, so I set a cookie that lasts for 1 day. This way, when they hit login.php it redirects them to cms.php and that page sees the session variable has been set by login.php and allows the redirect.

Comment: ...? When using a session you're already setting a *session cookie*. What's the other cookie for? Also, why are you setting it via Javascript instead of via HTTP headers?

Comment: I have a rudimentary understanding of how they differ. I thought a PHP session was server-side? The other cookie is to save the fact that they have already logged in. I have never tried HTTP headers, I just googled 'how to set cookies with javascript'. 

After I got that working, I decided I wanted to protect the CMS page from being looked at by anyone who hadn't come through the login page, so I set a session variable from the login page and if it isn't found when you attempt to go to the CMS, then you are redirected.

Comment: I'm acutely aware that there may be a much better way (read: simpler) to do this than what I have done; it's why I turned to the experts on stackoverflow. :) You have to forgive me for the fact that I am learning this on my own, so I may be overcomplicating matters with my approach, but I'm learning each 'task' one at a time. Now I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to combine them.

Comment: _“I thought a PHP session was server-side?”_ – the _data_ you put into the session is stored on the server, yes. But the client has to send the session-id with every request, so that the server can recognize the client and associate the _right_ session data to him. And that is usually done using a cookie to store and pass the session-id. So instead of an extra cookie, just write the login status into your session, and access it from there to check whether or not the current user is logged in.

Comment: @CBroe will the session cookie not expire when the session does?

Comment: I think it just makes more sense to set a cookie using PHP saying that the user logged in, right? Then the login page can redirect if that cookie is found, and the CMS will display it's contents if the cookie is found. I think this is less convoluted than what I was doing originally.

Comment: _“I think it just makes more sense to set a cookie using PHP saying that the user logged in, right?”_ – well if you just mean something like `loginstatus=true` … every user could set such a cookie for himself, and then access your site, without actually logging in first.

Comment: @CBroe Would a purely PHP Session approach be 'more secure' than a simple cookie by itself?

Comment: Yes, at least if your cookie would hold just a static value that everyone can easily fake.